# Multiple AJAX calls with multiple loading indicators

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page in ASP.net MVC where I am using ajax call to load data for each div there are 6 of them. I have wrote two methods to show/hide loading indicator for the div like this.

```
$("#divId").loading(); 
$("#divId").stopLoading();
```

Here is one of my ajax call(All are same)

```
 $.getJSON("RequestPerameters", function (result, textStatus, jqHXR)
    {
        $("#today-apt").stopLoading();

       //Populate Today-apt div
    });
```

Definations for loading and stopLoading mehtods

```
    (function ($)
    {
        $.fn.Loading = function ()
        {
            $(this).children().hide();
            $(this).append("<img src='/Images/loading.gif' class='center-block' />");
            return this;
        };

        $.fn.stopLoading = function ()
        {
            $(this).children(":visible").remove();
            $(this).children().show();
            return this;
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Below is the ready method from where the ajax calls are being made.

```
 $(function ()
{


    $("#up-appointments").Loading();
    $("#mySales").Loading();
    $("#todays-appointments").Loading();
    $("#today-performance").Loading();
    $("#c-feed").Loading();

    loadPerformanceModal();
    loadAppointments();
    loadPTOs();// should be right after laodAppointments
    loadMySales();
    loadUpCommingAppointments();
    loadUpCommingPTOs(); // should be right after loadUpCommingAppointments
    loadCustomFeedback();
});
```

It works fine . The problem occurs some time when data is loaded into the div
but the indicator does hide it self.Most of the time it works fine .

Can you tell me if this is because of multiple simultaneous AJAX calls? And if there's any workaround.

Comment: 1) Add code 2) Place the code in to a snippet or code block, not plaintext

Comment: you need to write a service that manages ajax requests and in each request you can show indicator. After response or error you can stop indicator.

Comment: @user3087839 I am doing so As It is not a service but I am hiding the indicator on AJAX result. On error there is another scenario. Rest Assured AJAX calls are succeeding as the data gets populated in the div .

Comment: _"Can you tell me if this is because of multiple simultaneous AJAX calls? And if there's any workaround."_ Use different elements as "loading indicators" for each request? Or, if you are expecting same indicator to show/hide corresponding to multiple requests, create logic to handle measuring the success of multiple requests.

Comment: @guest271314 Good one. I have tried that but as the number of divs varies from 2 to like 100 . Adding so many indicator is not wise also Different indicators distort the whole UI of the page.

Comment: There are not any error on console right? I need to know what are you doing in stopLoading() method. You can call $("#today-apt").hide();

Comment: Only one call to `$.getJSON()` appears at `javascript` at Question. What do you mean by "multiple simultaneous AJAX calls"?

Comment: Yes there is no error in console. And I am updating the question to include stopLoading() method

Comment: try async:false in ajax call,so it is execute one process at one time.

Comment: @Pathik thanks for the suggestion but its kind of a requirement to have these call run async.

Comment: Note, the method is named `$.fn.Loading`, though you are calling `.loading()`? How are "multiple simultaneous AJAX calls" initiated? Only one call to `$.getJSON()` appears at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 yes I am aware of that I did not copy the line $("#divId").loading(); I just wrote it actual one is calling .Loading

Comment: `$.fn.Loading != $.fn.loading`. Can you describe the multiple simultaneous ajax portion of Question?

Comment: @guest271314 The one call in the question is general structure as all calls are following this pattern. On how are these initiated each call is in separate function and function are called from document.ready method

Comment: @guest271314 I am updating question to add initialization code might help you.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question and reproduce the issue  at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co?

Comment: Everything seems valid to me :).

Comment: Maybe you can remove image by id or class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` `$.getJSON()` call from the function calls, use `$.when()`, `.then()` to chain the asynchronous calls within `$.when()`

```
$(function () {

    var loadingDivs = "#up-appointments,#mySales,#todays-appointments"
                      + ",#today-performance,#c-feed";
    $(loadingDivs).Loading();

    $.when(loadPerformanceModal()
      , loadAppointments()
        .then(function() {return loadPTOs()})// should be right after    
      , laodAppointments()
      , loadMySales()
      , loadUpCommingAppointments()
        .then(function() {return loadUpCommingPTOs()}) // should be right after  
      , loadUpCommingAppointments()
      , loadCustomFeedback()
    )
    .then(function(...responses) {
      console.log(responses)
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown)
    });
});
```